# JavaScript to download CSV file truncates the file

Tags: javascript, csv, download

Running the `JavaScript` Code below locally in `Visual Studio (using the IIS server)` downloads the requested `csv` file perfectly. The `csv` file is small at `89Kb`, and contains `726 rows`.

However, when deployed remotely to the `Azure` server the requested `csv` file is truncated, containing `453 full rows` and a partial last row.

The JavaScript is shown below:

```
const csvBlob = new Blob([csv], { type: 'octet-stream' });
const csvUrl = URL.createObjectURL(csvBlob);

const link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = csvUrl;
link.setAttribute('download', filename);
link.style.visibility = 'hidden';
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
document.body.removeChild(link);
```

Using `{ type: 'text/csv;charset=UTF-8' }` also results in a truncated file when downloaded from the `Azure` server, but also works locally.